# Trying to nest if statements in Jekyll/Liquid

Tags: html, templates, jekyll, liquid

having trouble nesting the following code. Where am I going wrong?

I just want to have some events show if the day is monday and then within that each event has a number of stars so I want to have another if statement that pulls that amount of stars and displays the correct image.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">
  {% for event in site.nottingham_events %}
  {% if event.day == "Monday" %}
    <div class="event-guide-event">
      <img class="event-guide-event--thumbnail" src="/img/thumb.jpg" 
      alt="">
      <h2>{{ event.name }}</h2>
      <p>When: {{ event.time }}</p>
      <h3>Where: {{ event.bar }}</h3>
      <h3>Hosted By: {{ event.brand }}</h3>
      {% if event.stars =="3" %}
      <img src="/img/events/3-stars.png" alt="Everyone">
      {% endif %}
      {% if event.stars =="2" %}
      <img src="/img/events/2-stars.png" alt="Enthusiasts and 
      Beginners">
      {% endif %}
      {% if event.stars =="1" %}
      <img src="/img/events/1-star.png" alt="Expert">
    {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: How does nottingham_events looks like? What is not working?

Comment: Is this: `{% if event.stars =="2" %}` supposed to be an integer: `{% if event.stars == 2 %}`? Really you should be using `{% elsif %}` or `{% case %}` too.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing my logic, because you can't nest *if statements* in Liquid.